# Raspberry Pi, tkinter, on screen counter on trigger, image issue

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple script that shows a kill button at the bottom of the screen and a counter when a GPIO is triggered.  I would like the counter to display in the middle of the screen.  But, it actually pushes the "kill" button up and displays the counter under it.  How can I fix this to display my counter in the middle of the screen?

Startup Screen

[image]

Screen After GPIO

[image]

```
from time import sleep  # Allows us to call the sleep function to slow down our loop
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO # Allows us to call our GPIO pins and names it just GPIO
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  # Set's GPIO pins to BCM GPIO numbering
BUTTON_1 = 23           # Sets our input pins
BUTTON_2 = 24           # Sets our input pins
BUTTON_3 = 25           # Sets our input pins
GPIO.setup(BUTTON_1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # Set our input pin to be an input, with internal pullup resistor on
GPIO.setup(BUTTON_2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # Set our input pin to be an input, with internal pullup resistor on
GPIO.setup(BUTTON_3, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # Set our input pin to be an input, with internal pullup resistor on

counter = 0 
def counter_label(label):
  def count():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    #m = Label(text=str(counter))
    #m.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES)
    #m.config(bg="#3366ff", justify=CENTER, font=("calibri", 29))
    label.config(text=str(counter), bg="#000000", justify=CENTER, font=("calibri", 29))
    label.pack(side=TOP)
  count()



# Create functions to run when the buttons are pressed
def Input_1(channel):
    # Put whatever Button 1 does in here
    print ('Button 1')
    counter_label(label);

def Input_2(channel):
    # Put whatever Button 2 does in here
    print ('Button 2');

def Input_3(channel):
    # Put whatever Button 3 does in here
    print ('Button 3');

class SplashScreen(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, width=0.8, height=0.6, useFactor=True):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        # get screen width and height
        ws = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = self.master.winfo_screenheight()
        w = (useFactor and ws*width) or width
        h = (useFactor and ws*height) or height
        # calculate position x, y
        x = (ws) - (w) 
        y = (hs) - (h)
        self.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (ws, hs, 0, 0))

        self.master.overrideredirect(True)
        self.lift()

# Wait for Button 1 to be pressed, run the function in "callback" when it does, also software debounce for 300 ms to avoid triggering it multiple times a second
GPIO.add_event_detect(BUTTON_1, GPIO.BOTH, callback=Input_1, bouncetime=200) 
GPIO.add_event_detect(BUTTON_2, GPIO.BOTH, callback=Input_2, bouncetime=200) # Wait for Button 2 to be pressed
GPIO.add_event_detect(BUTTON_3, GPIO.BOTH, callback=Input_3, bouncetime=200) # Wait for Button 3 to be pressed


root = tk.Tk()
#root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

sp = SplashScreen(root)
sp.config(bg="#000000")

sw = root.winfo_screenwidth()
sh = root.winfo_screenheight()
print ("sw:", sw)
print ("sh:", sh)

Button(sp, text="Press this button to kill the program", bg='red', command=root.destroy).pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

root.title("Counting Seconds")
label = tk.Label(root, fg="green")
label.pack()

root.mainloop()


# Start a loop that never ends
#while True:
    # Put anything you want to loop normally in here
   # sleep(.1);           # Sleep for a full minute, any interrupt will break this so we are just saving cpu cycles.
```

Answer (score 1):

You must SplashScreen as a label parent, besides moving them to the center with place giving you relative locations, you should not use `pack()` for label:

```
label = tk.Label(sp, fg="green")
label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
```

Also modifies the `counter_label` function

```
counter = 0 
def counter_label(label):
  def count():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    #m = Label(text=str(counter))
    #m.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES)
    #m.config(bg="#3366ff", justify=CENTER, font=("calibri", 29))
    label.config(text=str(counter), bg="#000000", justify=CENTER, font=("calibri", 29))
  count()
```

[image]